# SWIFT: Struggling to add random names within an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

My app is very basic, First you enter all the player names, all those names get stored into a Array. Second the last screen pops up with a sentence, once you click on a button the sentence change to the second element of the array, click again it goes to the third etc.. the easiest way I could done that is by each time clicking it removes the array[0].

but in this array sentences I have included the player names (the ones you type in the beginning, but I takes a random element of the player names array. so the random statement works fine but it does not take a random name every time I click. The first random element it takes it sticks with ... please help

ps: when I print(p1) it changes but it does not change on the screen/app

```
import UIKit

var q = ["Hello " + p1,"wie is die beste ? Malcolm is !!!","Hoe Gaan Dit " + p1 + " en met jou ook " + p2,"Gaan Baie goed dankie " + p1,"Wat Maak jy " + p2,"Ek sit maar hierso " + p2,"We are getting somewhere " + p1,"blah blah blah hoe gaan daai song van eminem alweer " + p1,"EK vorder met apps maak elke dag hehe " + p2,""]

var p1 = ""
var p2 = ""
var random = [String]()

var pc1 = 0
var pc2 = 0

/////////////////////////

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
  //chosing a random player

  pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
  pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))

  if pc1 == pc2{
     pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
     pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
  }

  p1 = players[pc1]
  p2 = players[pc2]

  if q[0] != "" {
    dis.text = q[0]
    q.remove(at: 0)
  } else {
    dis.text = ""
  }   
}
```

Comment: You need to move `var q = [...]` into the function, after you set `pc1` and `pc2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the concatenation. You are creating an array of strings that have concatenation inside of them, when the array is called from inside the action, the array's concatenation is not being used.

The best solution is for you to create the array of quotes inside the scope of the action method and increment on the index until you have reached the total count of the array.

For this you have to create a variable outside of the method's scope, and increment on it until you have reached the same number as your q's count. Once you get to the same count, you will reset it back to 0 and the process starts all over again.

Example:

```
var p1 = ""
var p2 = ""
var random = [String]()

var pc1 = 0
var pc2 = 0
var index = 0


/////////////////////////

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
   //chosing a random player

 pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
 pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))

 if pc1 == pc2{
     pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
     pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
 }

 p1 = players[pc1]
 p2 = players[pc2]

 // Array of quotes is now inside the scope of the method.
 var q = ["Hello " + p1,"wie is die beste ? Malcolm is !!!","Hoe Gaan Dit " + p1 + " en met jou ook " + p2,"Gaan Baie goed dankie " + p1,"Wat Maak jy " + p2,"Ek sit maar hierso " + p2,"We are getting somewhere " + p1,"blah blah blah hoe gaan daai song van eminem alweer " + p1,"EK vorder met apps maak elke dag hehe " + p2,""]

    // Using the quote
    dis.text = q[index]

    // Incrementing index
    index += 1

    // Keeping track of the index's count
    // and reseting it back to 0
    if index == q.count {
        index = 0
    }
}
```

This will help you with your problem, assuming that this is what you are looking for in your app's implementation.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The text in `q` will only be set once if it is an attribute of your ViewController. If you want to update it depending on your usernames, it needs to be created after you choose the player names:

```
import UIKit

var currentIndex = 0
var p1 = ""
var p2 = ""
var random = [String]()

var pc1 = 0
var pc2 = 0

/////////////////////////

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
  //chosing a random player

  pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
  pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))

  if pc1 == pc2{
     pc1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
     pc2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(players.count)))
  }

  p1 = players[pc1]
  p2 = players[pc2]

  var q = ["Hello " + p1,"wie is die beste ? Malcolm is !!!","Hoe Gaan Dit " + p1 + " en met jou ook " + p2,"Gaan Baie goed dankie " + p1,"Wat Maak jy " + p2,"Ek sit maar hierso " + p2,"We are getting somewhere " + p1,"blah blah blah hoe gaan daai song van eminem alweer " + p1,"EK vorder met apps maak elke dag hehe " + p2,""]

  if q[0] != "" {
    dis.text = q[currentIndex]
    currentIndex += 1
  } else {
    dis.text = ""
  }   
}
```

Comment: Hi, Yes that will work but the I have an issue every time I click it stays on q[0]. SO the sentence stays on "hello" + p1, the name changes randomly but the q[0] never deletes.  how I can I switch to the next array with a click of the button ?

Comment: Store the index that you are up to - instead of always using `0`.